# Count all observed factor levels, also those that aren't observed

Tags: r, count, aggregate, plyr, r-factor

We have the DF

```
df <- data.frame(group=as.factor(rep(c("UP","DOWN"),6)),variables=(rep(c("sex","smoke","sport"),each=4))
             ,values=as.factor(c(1,1,1,0  ,1,1,0,0, 1,1,1,1)))

   group variables values
1     UP       sex      1
2   DOWN       sex      1
3     UP       sex      1
4   DOWN       sex      0
5     UP     smoke      1
6   DOWN     smoke      1
7     UP     smoke      0
8   DOWN     smoke      0
9     UP     sport      1
10  DOWN     sport      1
11    UP     sport      1
12  DOWN     sport      1
>
```

Now I want to know all counts of all levels

```
library(plyr)
```

This command does almost perfectly what I want

```
count(df, c("variables", "group", "values"))

 variables group values freq
1      sex  DOWN     0    1
2      sex  DOWN     1    1
3      sex    UP     1    2
4    smoke  DOWN     0    1
5    smoke  DOWN     1    1
6    smoke    UP     0    1
7    smoke    UP     1    1
8    sport  DOWN     1    2
9    sport    UP     1    2
```

I also want to count the factor levels that arent observed. Like I did per hand in the following output.

```
 variables group values freq
1      sex  DOWN     0    1
2      sex  DOWN     1    1
3      sex    UP     0    0  <-- 
4      sex    UP     1    2
5    smoke  DOWN     0    1
6    smoke  DOWN     1    1
7    smoke    UP     0    1  
8    smoke    UP     1    1
9    sport  DOWN     0    0  <--
10   sport  DOWN     1    2
11   sport    UP     0    0  <--
12   sport    UP     1    2
```

**How can I achieve the above output?**

Comment: One option is to use `expand.grid` to make a df of all possibilities and then `join` this with the results of `count`

Comment: can someone precode it for this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this also with `data.table` with less lines of code:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- setDT(df)
cj <- CJ(dt$variables, dt$group, dt$values, unique = TRUE)
dt[, .N, keyby = c("variables", "group", "values")][cj][is.na(N), N := 0]

print(dt)    
    variables group values N
 1:       sex  DOWN      0 1
 2:       sex  DOWN      1 1
 3:       sex    UP      0 0
 4:       sex    UP      1 2
 5:     smoke  DOWN      0 1
 6:     smoke  DOWN      1 1
 7:     smoke    UP      0 1
 8:     smoke    UP      1 1
 9:     sport  DOWN      0 0
10:     sport  DOWN      1 2
11:     sport    UP      0 0
12:     sport    UP      1 2
```

#### Explanation

`setDT()` converts a `data.frame` to a `data.table` *by reference*, ie, without copying.

`CJ()` is a cross join. It forms a `data.table` from the cross product of the vectors. Thus, it's the `data.table` version of `expand.grid`.
The parameter `unique = TRUE` is a convenient alternative to wrapping each argument in `level()` or `unique()`.

The counting by groups is done with `dt[, .N, keyby = c("variables", "group", "values")]`:

```
   variables group values N
1:       sex  DOWN      0 1
2:       sex  DOWN      1 1
3:       sex    UP      1 2
4:     smoke  DOWN      0 1
5:     smoke  DOWN      1 1
6:     smoke    UP      0 1
7:     smoke    UP      1 1
8:     sport  DOWN      1 2
9:     sport    UP      1 2
```

Now, `dt[, .N, keyby = c("variables", "group", "values")][cj]` (right) joins the `CJ()` result with all possible combinations.

Finally, `[is.na(N), N := 0]` replaces all `NA`s in column `N` by `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
library(plyr)
d1 <- count(df, c("variables", "group", "values"))
d2 <- expand.grid(list(levels(df$variables), levels(df$group), levels(df$values)))
d2$freq <- 0
colnames(d2) <- colnames(d1)
m <- merge(d1, d2, by = c("variables", "group", "values"), all.y  = T)[,-5]
m[is.na(m)] <- 0

   # variables group values freq.x
# 1        sex  DOWN      0      1
# 2        sex  DOWN      1      1
# 3        sex    UP      0      0
# 4        sex    UP      1      2
# 5      smoke  DOWN      0      1
# 6      smoke  DOWN      1      1
# 7      smoke    UP      0      1
# 8      smoke    UP      1      1
# 9      sport  DOWN      0      0
# 10     sport  DOWN      1      2
# 11     sport    UP      0      0
# 12     sport    UP      1      2
```

The idea is to make a data frame (named `d2`) in which all possible combinations of `variables` and `group` and `values` are generated and then merge it with `d1`.

Comment: I just tried the expand.grid method + merge like you. Expand.grid is very powerful. Thank you.

Comment: If there is a quicker way i'd love to know. But expand.grid works fine already.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea. You can replicate the rows based on `freq` variable. If the freq is 2 then the replicated row will have a unique rowname which we can target and change its `freq` and `values` to 0.

```
df1 <- plyr::count(df, c("variables", "group", "values"))
df2 <- df1[rep(row.names(df1), df1$freq),]
df2$freq[grep('.', row.names(df2), fixed = TRUE)] <- 0
df2$values[df2$freq == 0] <- 0

df2
#     variables group values freq
#1         sex  DOWN      0    1
#2         sex  DOWN      1    1
#3         sex    UP      1    2
#3.1       sex    UP      0    0
#4       smoke  DOWN      0    1
#5       smoke  DOWN      1    1
#6       smoke    UP      0    1
#7       smoke    UP      1    1
#8       sport  DOWN      1    2
#8.1     sport  DOWN      0    0
#9       sport    UP      1    2
#9.1     sport    UP      0    0
```

If you want to reset your rownames then, 
`row.names(df2) <- NULL`

Comment: Any other ways?

Comment: I dont think this way works with my big dataset. the groups are unbalanced and the freq number high as 130 sometimes. This would result in many many "new" generated rows"

Comment: then `expand.grid` as mentioned in comments is probably your best bet here